# How to prevent `doc` from indexing foreign macros?

Tags: indexing, package-writing

The [`doc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/doc) package, used for documenting LaTeX packages, has the ability to produce an index of all macros used in the package. Index entries can of of three types: where the macro is *described*, where it is *defined* and where it is *used*. However, if `\DisableCrossrefs` has not been specified, `doc` will index *every* macro in the code, including obviously useless entries like `\newcommand`, `\relax`, `\ifx` and so on. There is a command `\DoNotIndex`, which can be used to specify which macros should not be indexed. However, keeping the list intact is a tedious task that is prone to errors: each time you write a line of code, you need to think/check whether it introduces new unwanted index entries.

One "solution" is to say `\DisableCrossrefs` and forget about code indexing. I would want something different, namely, have only macros defined by *my* package listed in the index, which, IMO, makes more sense than blindly indexing everything but a set of explicit exceptions. More specifically, only names specified in the `macro` and `environment` environments should be tracked for where they are used, and other names should be omitted (for completeness, one can introduce a `\DoIndex` command, that is the opposite of `\DoNotIndex`, for exceptions that should be indexed anyway).

In the following example code, the desired output is that `\newcommand` and `\GenericInfo` are not in the index, but, at the same time, `\mymacro` is still in the index and shows all three references: where it is described, defined and used:

```
% \iffalse
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\EnableCrossrefs         
\CodelineIndex
\begin{document}
  \DocInput{test.dtx}
\end{document}
% \fi
%
% \DescribeMacro{\mymacro}
% Some meaningful description.
% 
% \StopEventually{\PrintIndex}
%
% \begin{macro}{\mymacro}
% Here we define the macro.
%    \begin{macrocode}
\newcommand{\mymacro}{hello}
%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{macro}
%
% And here we use it.
%    \begin{macrocode}
\PackageInfo{test}{\mymacro}
%    \end{macrocode}
% 
% \Finale
```

(Process it with two LaTeX runs with

```
makeindex -s gind.ist -o test.ind test.idx
```

between them.)

How can one achieve this result? Is there a package that already does this?

Comment: A package usually defines many auxiliary macros which are not listed with `\begin{macro}` or `\DescribeMacro`. In some cases the list for `\DoIndex` would be longer than the list for `\DoNotIndex`. I usually copy a list for `\DoNotIndex` from another package and add the items necessary for the current one.

Comment: @egreg: If one omits `\begin{macro}` for a new macro and uses the macro later, then he/she will end up with many "usage" entries in the index and no "definition" entry, which defeats the purpose of having the index. You could say that one can look at the first entry, but this is not semantically correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This version just indexes things that have a `|main` index entry. It could be adapted to filter on other things. It lists the things that need indexing in the `.aux` file so may take an extra run before `makeindex` so things stabilize, this is needed so that a later main entry enables indexing of earlier occurrences.

[image]

```
% \iffalse
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\makeatletter
\def\SpecialMainIndex#1{%
\@bsphack
\immediate\write\@auxout{%
\global\noexpand\expandafter\let\noexpand\csname MAIN:\noexpand\string\string#1\endcsname\noexpand\@empty}%
\SpecialIndex@{#1}{\encapchar main}\@esphack}
\def\SpecialIndex#1{%
\@bsphack
   \expandafter\ifx\csname MAIN:\string#1\endcsname\@empty
   \special@index{\expandafter\@gobble
                                      \string#1\actualchar
      \string\verb\quotechar*\verbatimchar\string#1\verbatimchar}%
   \fi
    \@esphack}

\EnableCrossrefs      
\EnableCrossrefs         
\CodelineIndex
\begin{document}
  \DocInput{test.dtx}
\end{document}
% \fi
%
% \DescribeMacro{\mymacro}
% Some meaningful description.
% 
% \StopEventually{\PrintIndex}
%
% \begin{macro}{\mymacro}
% Here we define the macro.
%    \begin{macrocode}
\newcommand{\mymacro}{hello}
%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{macro}
%
% And here we use it.
%    \begin{macrocode}
\PackageInfo{test}{\mymacro}
%    \end{macrocode}
% 
% \Finale
```

Comment: Does this work with `l3doc` as well? I  want to index only the macros that I created, whose tokens are prefixed by: `g@@` or `@@` or (some generic) `Name` (for those created using `xparse`). cc @joseph-wright