# index completely messed up in dtx file

Tags: indexing, dtx

I fight with the strange and useless entries of the index in dtx files.

It can reproduced with

```
% \iffalse
%<*driver>
\ProvidesFile{dtxcode.tex}
%</driver>
%
%<*driver>
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\EnableCrossrefs
\CodelineIndex
\RecordChanges
\listfiles

\begin{document}
  \DocInput{dtxcode.tex}
  \PrintIndex
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
%%
% \DescribeMacro{\foobar} Prints out foobar
% 
% \Finale
\endinput
```

the result is

`foobar= \subitem *+\foobar+, \usage{1}`

printed as shown here in the pdf.

Anyway: I would like to switch of the index functionality of doc.sty completely and replace it with my own. It tries to add EVERY latex command used in the index. With my current code this is hundrets of entries which have nothing to do with any command defined by the package.

Comment: Looks like there's a better answer at [package writing - How to prevent `doc` from indexing foreign macros? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46085/how-to-prevent-doc-from-indexing-foreign-macros)  or [hyperref - disable index creation in dtx file - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87670/disable-index-creation-in-dtx-file) although I didn't test it.

Comment: Also link to related question: Use [indexing - How to say to latexmk to use makeindex with special parameter (-s -g) - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314875/how-to-say-to-latexmk-to-use-makeindex-with-special-parameter-s-g) to make **`latexmk`** use `gind.ist`, and [package writing - How to prevent `doc` from indexing foreign macros? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46085/how-to-prevent-doc-from-indexing-foreign-macros) for one specific to `\DoNotIndex`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I run

```
makeindex -s gind.ist dtxcode
```

the content of the resulting `.ind` file is

```
 \begin{theindex} 
 \makeatletter\scan@allowedfalse
{\bfseries\hfil F\hfil}\nopagebreak

  \item \verb*+\foobar+\pfill \usage{1}

 \end{theindex}
```

If instead I run the wrong command

```
makeindex dtxcode
```

the resulting file contains

```
\begin{theindex}

  \item foobar=\verb
    \subitem *+\foobar+, \usage{1}

\end{theindex}
```

which is obviously wrong.

Indexing of a macro is suppressed by adding it as the argument to a `\DoNotIndex` command (there can be many, each receiving lists of macro names); for instance (from one `.dtx` of mine)

```
% \DoNotIndex{\newcommand,\newenvironment,\!,\@empty,\@gobble,\@gobbletwo}
% \DoNotIndex{\@ifpackageloaded,\@ifpackagewith,\@ifundefined,\@namedef}
% \DoNotIndex{\@nil,\@onlypreamble,\@tempa,\@tempb,\@tempswafalse,\def}
```

(I like that one command doesn't spill over the next line.)

It's customary that a DTX file has the `.dtx` extension, rather than `.tex`

Comment: Where does `-s gind.ist` come from?

Comment: `gind.ist` is the MakeIndex style specifically tailored for building the index for a `.dtx` file. See section 2.9 of the documentation of the `.dtx` format (`texdoc doc`)

Comment: Yes that corrects it. I would however prefer if the whole makeindex styleing was made in tex code as it does biblatex. The not indexing of commands is quite long (spills over 10 lines in the editor). To me this looks like a design problem of doc.sty.

Comment: Hello @egreg, I am working on a package which has some code which has `\somemacro\ some text` written. When I print the index with `l3doc` I see a list of symbols in which the program prints `\␣`. Now I understand why this happen, but as this isn't intended, I tried `\DoNotIndex{\ ,\othermacros}`, `\DoNotIndex{\csname\space\endcsname,\othermacros}`, but nothing seems to work. Can you suggest a fix?

Comment: @Niranjan Please, make a new question with the details and an example.

Comment: @egreg [Done](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/656406/174620).