# disable index creation in dtx file

Tags: hyperref, indexing, dtx

The following code is a minimal dtx code with ending .tex (only for the example).

I try to understand when an index created and when not, how this is influenced by the loading of hyperref and fail to see that the commands of doc.sty behave as documented.

```
% \iffalse
%<*driver>
\ProvidesFile{dtxcode.tex}
%</driver>
%
%<*driver>
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
% \usepackage{hyperref}

% \EnableCrossrefs  % (default) Every new macro name used within a macrocode or
                  % macrocode∗ environment will produce an index entry.
\DisableCrossrefs % turn off this feature
%
% If an index is created is determined by the use of the following
% declarations in the driver file preamble; if neither is used, no index is 
% produced.
% \PageIndex     % all index entries refer to their page number
% \CodelineIndex % index entries produced by \DescribeMacro and \DescribeEnv
               %  refer to page number but those produced by the macro
               %  environment refer to the code lines, 
               % which will be numbered automatically.
% \CodelineNumbered % no index is created, but the code lines are numbered


\RecordChanges
\listfiles

\begin{document}
  \DocInput{dtxcode.tex}
  \PrintIndex
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
%%
% \DescribeMacro{\foobar} Prints out foobar \index{test}
% 
% \Finale
\endinput
```

In this code the index is created with both `\DisableCrossrefs` and `DisableCrossrefs`

However If I load additionally the package hyperref the index disappears completely no matter what commands I activate. The index file created is nevertheless still the same - it is just not loaded.

And if I use `\CodelineNumbered` when hyperref is loaded the index appears again though it should not according to the docs of doc.sty.

To me this appears like a bug in ltxdoc/doc.sty.

EDIT:
Here a list of scenarios and their results. In all cases the idx file was deleted before execution and the pdf was created with `pdflatex`, `makeindex.exe -s gind.ist %.idx`, `pdflatex`

(a) no hyperref, \EnableCrossrefs and \PageIndex

```
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\EnableCrossrefs
\PageIndex
```

Index is created.

(b) no hyperref, \DisableCrossrefs and \PageIndex

```
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\DisableCrossrefs
\PageIndex
```

Index is created (but should not?)

(c) no hyperref, \DisableCrossrefs and \CodelineNumbered

```
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\DisableCrossrefs
\CodelineNumbered
```

Index is not created, empty idx file.

(d) no hyperref, \EnableCrossrefs and \CodelineNumbered

```
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\EnableCrossrefs
\CodelineNumbered
```

Index is not created. It seams that `\EnableCrossrefs` and `\DisableCrossrefs` do not control the index in contrast to the description of the documentation.

(e) with hyperref, \EnableCrossrefs and \PageIndex

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\EnableCrossrefs
\PageIndex
```

idx file is created but only self defined `\index` entries are displayed. In this case `test` but not `foobar`, though both are in the idx file with

```
\indexentry{foobar=\verb!*+\foobar+|usage|hyperpage}{1}
\indexentry{test|hyperpage}{1}
```

(f) with hyperref, \EnableCrossrefs and \CodelineNumbered

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\EnableCrossrefs
\CodelineNumbered
```

No idx file is created as without hyperref.

To summarize: With loading of hyperref the creation of the index files is not influenced, but the index entries of doc.sty arenot included during compilation in the pdf.

Comment: (a) The described scenarios always create `dtxcode.glo` because of `\RecordChanges` that is converted by `makeindex -s gglo -o dtxcode.gls dtxcode.glo`. (b) I don't get a `dtxcode.idx` with/without `hyperref` or with/without `\CodelineNumbered`. Please make more clear, which scenario you are using and which files are created by a scenario.

Comment: I described the problem in more detail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### `\EnableCrossrefs` and `\DisableCrossrefs`

These macros control, whether command names inside `macrocode` or `macrocode*` environments are indexed. From the [documentation of package `doc`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/doc.pdf):

> 2.7 Cross-referencing all macros used
>
> `\DisableCrossrefs`, `\EnableCrossrefs`
>
> As already mentioned, every new macro name used within a `macrocode`
>   or `macrocode*` environment will produce an index entry. In this way
>   one can easily find out where a specific macro is used.  Since TeX is
>   considerably slower when it has to produce such a bulk of index
>   entries one can turn off this feature by using `\DisableCrossrefs` in
>   the driver file. To turn it on again just use `\EnableCrossrefs`.

### Index generation

As usual the index generation is triggered by `\makeindex`. Macros `\CodelineIndex` or `\PageIndex` also call `\makeindex`.

### Discussion of the cases

I have extended `dtxcode.tex` to show the effect of `\EnableCrossrefs`:

```
%    \begin{macrocode}
\def\foobar{...}
%    \end{macrocode}
```

(a) no `hyperref`, `\EnableCrossrefs` and `\PageIndex`:

```
\indexentry{foobar=\verb!*+\foobar+|usage}{1}
\indexentry{test}{1}
\indexentry{def=\verb!*+\def+}{1}
\indexentry{foobar=\verb!*+\foobar+}{1}
```

⇒ Full page based index.

(e) with `hyperref`, `\EnableCrossrefs` and `\PageIndex`:

```
\indexentry{foobar=\verb!*+\foobar+|usage|hyperpage}{1}
\indexentry{test|hyperpage}{1}
\indexentry{def=\verb!*+\def+|hyperpage}{1}
\indexentry{foobar=\verb!*+\foobar+|hyperpage}{1}
```

⇒ Full page based index, but wrong index entry for `\DescribeMacro`/`\usage`, because `hyperref` does not support the index format of `doc` directly.

(b) no `hyperref`, `\DisableCrossrefs` and `\PageIndex`:

```
\indexentry{foobar=\verb!*+\foobar+|usage}{1}
\indexentry{test}{1}
```

⇒ Index entries for `\DescribeMacro` and `\index` only.

(c), (d), and (f) no/with `hyperref`, `\DisableCrossrefs`/`\EnableCrossrefs` and `\CodelineNumbered`:

⇒ No index at all, because one of `\makeindex` or `\PageIndex` or `\CodelineIndex` is missing.

### Linked index entries

Package [`hypdoc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hypdoc) can be used instead of `hyperref`: It loads package `hyperref`, disable `hyperref`'s index support (`hyperindex=false`) and implements its own support for package `doc`'s index commands. However, `hyperpage` is not added for plain `\index` commands, thus it needs to be added (`\index{test|hyperpage}`).

```
% \iffalse
%<*driver>
\ProvidesFile{dtxcode.tex}
%</driver>
%
%<*driver>
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{hypdoc}

\EnableCrossrefs

\PageIndex
%\CodelineIndex

\RecordChanges
\listfiles

\begin{document}
  \DocInput{dtxcode.tex}
  \PrintIndex
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
%
% \DescribeMacro{\foobar} Prints out foobar \index{test|hyperpage}.
%
%    \begin{macrocode}
\def\foobar{...}
%    \end{macrocode}
%
% \Finale
\endinput
```

`dtxcode.idx` then contains:

```
\indexentry{foobar=\verb!*+\foobar+|hdclindex{2}{usage}}{1}
\indexentry{test|hyperpage}{1}
\indexentry{def=\verb!*+\def+|hdpindex{}}{1}
\indexentry{foobar=\verb!*+\foobar+|hdpindex{}}{1}
```

and all entries are linked.